# Using one layout file for multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm working on ftp client for android right now, In my app I wanna have 2 fragments, one for local file system and one for the remote, even though they obviosuly function differently I still want them to have the same layout, as they should look the same.
So I've been wondering, is it ok to use the same layout for different fragments or should I just copy to 2 different file?
Doesn't know if that is relevant but the fragments will definitely be active on the same time as I intend they'll both be on a pager viewer.
Also, if you could answer more generally, could two different "particles" use the same layout without problems?
Preety nooby question, but I'm new to android so...

Comment: Yes. You could use the same layout.

Comment: What do you mean by "particles"?

Comment: I meant activities, fragments, dialog boxes, etc...anything that 2 of them could use one layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no problem with this.**

You can use one blue-print to build a whole bunch of houses. This is the exact same. Eventually, you might build them with separate layout files, but for now, one is fine.